# Random dynamical system in layman's terms?

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems

As of now, the formal definition of a *random dynamical system* is a bit over my head. And many of the papers and books on this subject are not exactly "introductory-friendly." I still have a lot of years to go before I fully understand this topic, or rather, fully understand the prerequisites for this topic.

I was wondering if someone could provide me a definition of a random dynamical system in layman's terms. For example, how would you describe random dynamical systems to a group of high schoolers?

Comment: Basically, you have a particle that moves around and for whatever reason you don't know what exactly it will do, so you want to give a probabilistic description of its path. One nice visualization of how this might come up is the classical scenario for Brownian motion, where you have a relatively heavy particle like a grain of dust moving around amongst a large number of relatively light particles like water molecules. Then unless you're prepared to describe how the water molecules move, you must concede that the motion of the dust is random...but you can still say *something* about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A random dynamical system is simply another name for an iteration that at each time $n$ selects a map $f_n$ to apply taken out from a pool of maps, "randomly".

The main concern with this simple description is that it does not specify what "randomly" means. Usually it means that the map $f_n$ is chosen according to some probably distribution to the former pool of maps. In more mathematical terms this simply means that we need to consider maps $f_n(\omega)$ depending on the time $n$ at which we apply the map and $\omega$ which is the variable for which we specify a random distribution, given by a probability measure.

The natural mathematical field where you study these is ergodic theory, notably smooth ergodic theory (which is where we study the ergodic properties of smooth maps that leave invariant a measure like Lebesgue measure). The area of random dynamical systems is only a subfield of ergodic theory.

Comment: I would quite strongly dispute that last sentence. (Just in general "subfield" descriptions are usually either misleading or mostly vacuous IME.)

Comment: Your right, sure.